# INSERT INTO sql query is using variable string rather than field name

Tags: php, sql

Getting really confused surrounding this INSERT INTO. It should insert three fields into the table, `userID`, `activateKey` and `isActivated`.

The activateKey is a 25 letter randomly generated key such as `63n20kw24ba1mlox34e8n2awv`

The userID comes from another table and is set by auto_increment.

The isActivated is always 0 at this stage.

It seems like quite a simple INSERT statement

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO activations (userID,activationKey,isActivated) VALUES (".$userID.",".$activateKey.",'0')"))
  {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

However it doesn't work when I include the `$activateKey` field. What it does is try to search the string variable `$activateKey` as a column name. The error I get is:

```
Error description: Unknown column '63n20kw24ba1mlox34e8n2awv' in 'field list'
```

Of course there is no such column as `63n20kw24ba1mlox34e8n2awv`, this is the data I'm trying to insert, hence why it's in the `VALUES` section. Any ideas why it's trying to search this as the column name?

Edit to clarify: the var is **activate**Key, the column name is **activation**Key

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit. The correct var is `activateKey`. The column name is `activationKey` - I changed them to be different to try and avoid confusion between the two but I seem to have done the opposite!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the query in a different variable to avoid confusion, and PHP automatically substitutes variable names in strings in double quotes.

Try this:

```
<?php
  $query = "INSERT INTO activations (userID,activationKey,isActivated) VALUES($userID,'$activateKey','0')
  if (!mysqli_query($con,$query)
   {
     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not surrounding the values with quotes, that's why they get interpreted as variable names.
Use single quotes, like this:

```
"INSERT INTO activations (userID,activationKey,isActivated) VALUES
   ('".$userID."','".$activateKey."','0')"
```

However, be aware that stringing together query strings exposes you to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/), if that's a concern in your code you should [use parameterized queries](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).  In fact, using parameterized queries is always better.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this:

```
"INSERT INTO activations 
        (userID,activationKey,isActivated) 
 VALUES ('$userID','$activateKey','0')"
```

You dont need to use the concatenation (`.`) operator as variables will be interpolated into the string.

The single quotes tell mysql to treat the variables as literals instead of column names.

As a side note you would be better to use parameterized queries. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks. This is the cleanest answer. I'll look into paramaterized queries, though it looks like this uses the OO approach to mysqli whereas I'm using procedural?

Comment: It can be done oo or procedural style see [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It was a case of not properly wrapping the dynamic fields (the vars in the VALUES section) in ticks:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO activations (userID,activationKey,isActivated) VALUES ('".$userID."','".$activateKey."','0')"))
```

Instead of

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO activations (userID,activationKey,isActivated) VALUES (".$userID.",".$activateKey.",'0')"))
```

Might be a difficult one to spot. The variables still need to be 'in ticks' or they won't register as strings.

Answer (score 0):

As `activationKey` is a `string` column, you must use single quotes for `$activationKey`.
Try with:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO activations (userID,activationKey,isActivated)
     VALUES (".$userID.",'".$activateKey."','0')"))
```